# Zipping files to specified path in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have been learning python since few weeks. In one of the problem I have to zip the files contained in list to the specified path. I am using python in **Windows**.

python zipall.py C:\temp C:\example

should extract particular type of files from C:\example, which I did successfully in some list (say listX). Now the job is to make zip file C:\temp consisting of the **all** files in listX in zipped form. How to perform this operation in Python?

I have to make zip file in specified path (here C:\temp) containing all files that are contained in list (here listX).

I tried zipfile.ZipFile() as below:

```
zip_name = zipfile.ZipFile(tozip, 'w')
l=len(listX)
ctr=0
for thelist in listX:
    zip_name = zipfile.ZipFile(tozip+str(ctr), 'w')
    if ctr<=l:
        ctr+=1
    zip_name.write(thelist,'zip')
```

It certainly creates 'l' zip files but I have to create 'l' zip files within path given by tozip ('C:\temp' above)

Comment: A short answer is that you can do what you appear to want simply with the `zip.exe` program (available from Info-ZIP, for instance) without needing Python at all. If that does not meet your needs, it would be valuable to have some more detail in order to help you. For example, it isn't clear what you mean by list 'special'. Can you edit your question to include the file `zipall.py`? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`zipfile.ZipFile` creates the output ZIP archive for you in the location you want the ZIP file written to. But you need to give it a filename, not a directory name. From your description it sounds like `tozip` was set to `C:\temp`. In which case you should use `os.path.join` to construct a filename, like this:

```
import os.path
tozip = os.path.join(r'C:\temp', 'out.zip')
```

That should get you an archive created in the directory you want. Note that you may do this instead, using the handy 'tempfile' library to avoid hardcoding a Windows path into your script:

```
import os.path
from tempfile import gettempdir
tozip = os.path.join(gettempdir(), 'out.zip')
```

Now, as you're iterating through the list, I think you want to add each file one at a time to the single archive you're creating, right? Your code is looping through `listX`, but for each file in `listX` it's creating a *new* ZIP archive, and adding that file to the new archive. Also, as it goes through the list, because each time you're assigning the new ZIP archive to `zip_name`, you've completely forgotten about the archive that you *really* want to have your output in. So I think you want this instead:

```
theZip = zipfile.ZipFile(tozip, 'w')
for elem in listX:
    theZip.write(elem)
```